# Dynamically change column type when binding

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `DataGridView` bound to one of my Binding Adapters. There's a column in my grid that corresponds to a `"type"` of an attachment (i.e ".pdf"). This is being displayed in the grid view column as text (as expected). I want to be able to change the value of the column to be an image to signify the type. For example, if the type is a `PDF`, I want there to be an image of a `PDF` document in the column rather than the text `".pdf"`.

Is there a way I can do this dynamically as the cells are added? Or would like have to be something that's done after all the cells are loaded?

Cheers.

Comment: have you tried any idea yet ?Yes you can do this dynamically but why ?Use template field instead of `BoundField` use `imagebutton` but this will give you a constant image for all `PdF` or else add its image dynamically on `RowBound` event or do you have any image for that `Pdf` already ?

Comment: It's a confusing question? Do you want to change the column type? The column name or the content of a column field?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use an image and have a few icons with corresponding names.

E.g. pdf.png, word.png

Then build the link like this:

```
<img src="<%# LinkRoot + Eval("type").ToString() + ".png" %>" height="32" width="32" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to draw the images on the column `type` yourself, of course the drawn image is corresponding to the `text` (describing file type, e.g: `.pdf`,`.txt`,...). You have to prepare all the images yourself, if there is not any corresponding image to an unknown file type, you can use a `Unknown file type image`. To draw an image on a cell, you have to handle the event `CellPainting`, here is the code you can try:

```
//Dictionary to store the pairs of `text` and the corresponding image
Dictionary<string, Image> dict = new Dictionary<string, Image>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
//load data for your dict
dict["Unknown"] = yourUnknownImage;//This should always be added
dict[".pdf"] = yourPdfImage;
dict[".txt"] = yourTxtImage;
//.....
//CellPainting event handler for your dataGridView1
//Suppose the column at index 1 is the type column.
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e){
   if(e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.RowIndex > -1){
     var image = dict["Unknown"];
     if(e.Value != null) {
        Image img;
        if(dict.TryGetValue(e.Value.ToString(), out img)) image = img;            
     }
     //Draw the image
     e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(2,2, e.Bounds.Height-4, e.Bounds.Height-4));
   }
}
```